# What does に mean as in 川沿いに歩く?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に

I found the following example sentence in my dictionary.

> 川沿いに歩く。Walk along a river.

I looked it up and found out that 川沿い is a noun. Then に should be a particle. But here clearly it doesn’t indicate the location of existence or the direction of motion. So what usage of に is this?

Comment: It seems to me to be indicating *direction of motion*.  The direction is *along the river*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase A沿いにB means "do B along A".
It's commonly used with rivers, railway tracks, roads, anything long.